# NFC communication between Android and Symbian

Tags: android, symbian, symbian3

I'm trying to establish NFC communication between Android and Symbian Belle, is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. NFC is just like any other communication technology (like bluetooth etc), and can be made to work cross platform.

While platform specific APIs (like Android beam) will not work across platforms, you should still be able to implement your own app that can send data between devices.

The Android device will read the Symbian one as a normal NFC tag, and the Symbian device will do the same to the Android one.

[Symbian NFC tutorial](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Developing_NFC_Applications)

[Android NFC Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html)